# Having issues Looping over simple JSON array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

When I loop over the ajax array, it is returning the index and value incorrectly.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/ajax/deal_start_times/'+$pid,
    success : function(data){
        var tmp = "";
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            tmp = tmp + index + '|' + value + "<br />";
        });
        alert(tmp);

    }
});
```

The ajax call to: '/ajax/deal_start_times/'+$pid' returns:

```
["02:00","03:00","05:00","08:00","10:00","12:00"]
```

Here is the alert output:

0| 
1| 
2| 
3| 
4|

5|

6|[
7|"
8|0
9|2
10|:
11|0
12|0
13|"
14|,
15|"
16|0
17|2
18|:
19|0
20|0
21|"
22|,
23|"
24|0
25|2
26|:
27|0
28|0
29|"
30|,
31|"
32|0
33|2
34|:
35|0
36|0
37|"
38|,
39|"
40|0
41|2
42|:
43|0
44|0
45|"
46|,
47|"
48|0
49|2
50|:
51|0
52|0
53|"
54|]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX request, otherwise `data` is just a string.